# Android html.form html

Tags: java, android

I'd like to read html tags to a TextView, so I have done this:

```
titolo = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.articolo.titolo);
        testo = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.articolo.testo);
        titolo.setText(db.getTitolo());
        testo.setText(db.getTesto());
        testo.setText(Html.fromHtml(testo));
```

But i have an errore here: testo.setText(Html.fromHtml(testo)); Why?

This application retrieves data from a database so I hope that if I write into the database, for example  hello  this is formatted as bold using html.fromhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you're sending TextView to fromHtml and you should deliver String variable. That String could contain HTML tags.

```
TextView testo = (TextView) findViewById(R.articolo.testo);
String formattedText = "This is <b>bold</b>";
testo.setText(Html.fromHtml(formattedText));
```

Of course you could get String from DB. I don't know how works your getTesto() method, but if it returns String you could write:

```
TextView testo = (TextView) findViewById(R.articolo.testo);
String formattedText = db.getTesto();
testo.setText(Html.fromHtml(formattedText));
```

Comment: last question ... Because if I put in the database of special characters in the application does not display them correctly? How can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

`public static Spanned fromHtml (String source)`

Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string. Any  tags in the HTML will display as a generic replacement image which your program can then go through and replace with real images.

This uses TagSoup to handle real HTML, including all of the brokenness found in the wild.

More info @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

This

```
 testo = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.articolo.testo); // textview initialized
```

This

```
 testo.setText(Html.fromHtml(testo)); // wrong
```

`fromHtml` takes a string as a argument

It should be

```
 testo.setText(Html.fromHtml("myhtmlString"));
```

Example :

```
  String s ="<b>"+"Hello"+"</b>";
  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

Comment: and then how can I do to " read " the html tags that I enter into the database?

Comment: you can use jsoup library fro that purpose to get the contents of html tags

Comment: @JohnSmoother what does this do  `testo.setText(db.getTesto())` display html data in textview?

Comment: Sorry, I have not figured out how to do. Basically I have a website where I write the texts, these texts they end up in the database. If for example I am writing <b> HELLO </ b> I would like the application displays the bold ... but I do not understand how to do. Can you explain with more details? Thanks

Comment: @JohnSmoother check this http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: Sorry, I just do not understand. Could you kindly post an example of how it should be using in my source? Many Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33000/discussion-between-john-smoother-and-raghunandan)